# Java: How to add JDK classes (e.g. javax.*) into custom JavaDoc indexes?

Tags: javadoc, java

I am creating an aggregated Javadoc for a big project.
It's a Maven project and I am using Maven Javadoc plugin 2.8.1.

I'd like to have javax.* classes in the indexes (i.e. left frames and the "all classes" index).
But even if I add these to @packages, they are only linked, not included.

**Is there a way to include JDK classes in the generaged Javadoc?**

Comment: Why don't you simply link to them? The Javadoc Plugin will do this for your as long as the javadocUrl is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to include them in the [sourcePath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourcepath) when you run the javadoc plugin. That means you'll have to have the javax.* source files available somewhere that maven can read them.

Note: it will take forever. That's one reason we tend to prefer linking to the existing ones.

Comment: The problem is, that `<sourcepath>` overrides what the plugin creates. Therefore I need to put whole project's sources in there. And that's yet not enough because the deps are needed too. And when I add deps, javadoc starts throwing a NPE. Details in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-582 .

Comment: There are some bugs in the bug database that appear to be exactly the same NPE you're seeing, such as [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5101868) and [here](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6442980). The suggested workaround is to remove the `-use` flag.